# Let $G$ be a graph which does not have 2 disjoint odd cycles. Prove that the Chromatic number is at most 5.

Tags: graph-theory

Hint: Suppose that the chromatic number is at least 6 and consider graphs induced by 3 colour classes.

Any hints would be appreciated. I do not understand what a graph induced by 3 colour classes are. They have not been defined in my lectures.

Thanks

Comment: If $Y$ is a subset of vertices of $V(G)$, then the subgraph *induced* by $Y$ is the subgraph whose vertices are $Y$ and whose edges are exactly *all* edges of $G$ that join two vertices in $Y$. So in your question, they mean choose any three colours, let $Y$ be the subset of all vertices that are coloured by one of those three colours and just consider edges between vertices coloured by one of those three colours.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the hint suggests:

Assume by contradiction that the chromatic number is at least 6. Pick one optimal coloring.

Define subgraphs $G_1, G_2$ the following way:

$G_1$ contains all the vertices colored with the first three colors and all the edges between these vertices. $G_2$ contains all the vertices colored with the other colors and all the edges between these vertices.

Now, one of $G_1, G_2$ doesn't contain an odd cycle, thus is 2 colorable. Recolor it with two colors, and prove that this gives a better coloring of $G$.

Comment: How do you know that you won't split the cycle?

Comment: An odd cycle that goes between $G_1$ and $G_2$ won't affect the proof.  It will still be true that you can't have two odd cycles where one is entirely contained in $G_1$ and the other is entirely contained in $G_2$.  That's all N.S.'s proof needs.

Comment: @Daniel The idea is that at least one of $G_1$ and $G_2$ doesn`t contain an odd cycle. If they split the cycle, even better.